# Wireshark not displaying non standard port FTP data packets

Tags: wireshark

I know this question may be off topic here but I believe network engineering is not right place for this question.
My question is that why wireshark doesn't shows non standard port like 8081 FTP packets(it shows all TCP packets) and what is needed to be done to see these packets?

Comment: So Wireshark sees the packets but does not label them as FTP traffic just as generic TCP. Therefore your question and especially the title may be a bit misleading.

Comment: Right click a packet of the stream and select "Decode as..." there you add a dissector assignment and assign the TCP port a different protocol such as FTP.

Comment: But contrary to above, it sometimes shows some FTP packets, not always!